# some content should be print on new page using window.print

Tags: php, jquery, printing

I am working on a project where I want to print a bill.It is running successfully but now I want to print particular content on a new page.

following is print screen image where I want to display terms and condition always on new page,at present it is displayed on same page depend upon bill content.I am new to new this any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance

[image: sdd]

EDIT :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function (){  

                $('.printpreview').click(function()
                {
                    $('.printpreview').hide()
                    window.print();

                });


            });
    </script>
```

Comment: sorry I didn't get you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make one class into stylesheet.

```
.printbreak {
page-break-before: always;
}
```

put your terms & condition content into div and give this class to this div

```
<div class="printbreak">
//terms & condition
</div>
```

If you want more information, then check http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Comment: Thanks you @GBD it works!! I was trying `page-break-after` now I change it to `page-break-before` and it run successfully.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

don't know how widely supported it is

```
@media print { table {page-break-after:always}}
```

or in javascript

```
*object*.style.pageBreakAfter="always"
```

more information can be found [on sitepoint's css page](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/page-break-after)!

Comment: css style, in case that isn't evident

Comment: sorry I am new to this please can you explain me with my example ?

Comment: It will be very helpful if you provide me some code.How this can be achieve in my code ?

Comment: you would have to show the code where you create the page for me to provide change recommendations